# How do I draw graph in sympy?

Tags: sympy

I'm high school student, and I'm writing a report about profile velocity.
I don't know much about differential equations and Python, but I have to use both of them.

I'm trying to induce the velocity from (ma = mg - kv), and caculate a and s from v.

I caculated v successfully, but I have few questions.

```
import sympy

init_printing()
%matplotlib inline 

(m, g, k, t) = symbols('m g k t')
v = Function('v')

deq = Eq( m*v(t).diff(t), m*g - k*v(t) )
eq = dsolve( deq, v(t) )

C1 = Symbol('C1')
C1_ic = solve( eq.rhs.subs( {t:0}), C1)[0]

r = expand(eq.subs({C1:C1_ic}))
```

1. the simple way to caculate C1 doesn't work

v(0) = 0

so I write

```
eq = dsolve( deq, ics={v(0):0})
```

but it has same result with

```
eq = dsolve( deq, v(t) )
```

2. how to caculate acc and draw a graph?

I try this code, but it doesn't work

```
a = diff(r, t)
r = dsolve( a, v(t))
r.subs({m:1, g:9.8, k:1})
plot( r , (t,0,100))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't get the same result from `eq = dsolve( deq, ics={v(0):0})`. Also you should declare `m`, `g` and `k` with `positive=True`.

```
In [50]: m, g, k = symbols('m g k', positive=True)

In [51]: t = Symbol('t')

In [52]: v = Function('v')

In [53]: deq = Eq( m*v(t).diff(t), m*g - k*v(t) )

In [54]: deq
Out[54]: 
  d                      
m⋅──(v(t)) = g⋅m - k⋅v(t)
  dt                     

In [55]: dsolve(deq, v(t))
Out[55]: 
              k⋅(C₁ - t)
              ──────────
                  m     
       g⋅m + ℯ          
v(t) = ─────────────────
               k        

In [56]: dsolve(deq, v(t), ics={v(0):0})
Out[56]: 
                ⎛     m⋅log(g)   m⋅log(m)   ⅈ⋅π⋅m⎞
              k⋅⎜-t + ──────── + ──────── + ─────⎟
                ⎝        k          k         k  ⎠
              ────────────────────────────────────
                               m                  
       g⋅m + ℯ                                    
v(t) = ───────────────────────────────────────────
                            k                     

In [57]: sol = dsolve(deq, v(t), ics={v(0):0}).rhs

In [58]: sol.expand()
Out[58]: 
           -k⋅t 
           ─────
             m  
g⋅m   g⋅m⋅ℯ     
─── - ──────────
 k        k     

In [59]: factor_terms(sol.expand())
Out[59]: 
    ⎛     -k⋅t ⎞
    ⎜     ─────⎟
    ⎜       m  ⎟
g⋅m⋅⎝1 - ℯ     ⎠
────────────────
       k
```

You can compute and plot the acceleration like

```
In [62]: sol = factor_terms(sol.expand())      

In [64]: a = sol.diff(t)

In [65]: a = sol.diff(t).subs({m:1, g:9.8, k:1})

In [66]: a
Out[66]: 
     -t
9.8⋅ℯ  

In [67]: plot(a, (t, 0, 100))
```